# Determine MySQL Database used by Magento Installation

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql

This question is probably fairly stupid but I installed a couple instances of Magento (for various reasons) and I made the MySQL database names very similar. In fact they only vary by some arbitrary numbering system I made up (and have since forgotten). All the installations have very few accounts, items, etc that were setup.

I'm wanting to do some house cleaning and get rid of the databases associated with installations I no longer use. Is there an easy way to figure out which is which or should I just back them all up and play roulette with the delete button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find the database name in the file `app/etc/local.xml` of each magento instance you have.
Figure out which instances you are not using and look in the file mentioned above at the tag `<dbname>`.

Comment: for magento2, it's in `app/etc/env.php`

Answer (score 2):

Just for posterity, in newer versions of Magento this is kept in app/etc/env.php